# Microsoft SQL Server - check constraint error when using stored procedure (msg 547)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, check-constraint

I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure add_new_customer, Line 6
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__customer__addres__09A971A2". The conflict occurred in database "AIT 732 - Bank", table "dbo.customer", column 'address_state'.

The following is table that I am attempting to update:

```
create table customer
(
cust_id numeric(10,0) not null identity primary key,
social_security_num numeric(9,0) not null,
first_name varchar(20) not null,
last_name varchar(20) not null,
primary_address varchar(50) not null,
address_zip_code numeric(5,0) not null,
address_state char(2) check (address_state in('md','pa','dc', 'de', 'wv', 'va','nj')),
gender char(1) not null check (gender in('m','f')),
phone_num numeric(10,0) null
)
```

this is the stored procedure i created:

```
create procedure add_new_customer
    (@social_sec numeric, @f_name varchar, @l_name varchar, @pri_address varchar, @zip numeric, @add_state char, @gender char, @phone numeric)
    as
    begin
        begin transaction
        insert into customer(
        social_security_num,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        primary_address,
        address_zip_code,
        address_state,
        gender,
        phone_num)
        values (
        @social_sec, 
        lower(@f_name), 
        lower(@l_name),
        lower(@pri_address), 
        @zip, 
        lower(@add_state), 
        lower(@gender), 
        @phone)
    if @@ERROR != 0 
    begin
        rollback transaction
        return @@error
    end
    commit transaction
 end
```

and last but not least, this is how I am calling procedure

```
add_new_customer 211118888, 'Bob', 'JONES', '222 some st', 21333, 'md', 'm', 4102227878
```

I've been messing with this for about and hour and can not figure out where that error is coming from. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is stating what the problem is; you have a CHECK CONSTRAINT that is being violated.

Comment: i get that, but I don't see how? it looks its the address_state constraint, but the value I put in should be fine.

Comment: You should add the length to all your char and varchar types in the stored proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stored proc parameter definition is `@add_state char` but this will truncate your input value of 'md' to 'm' which isn't a valid value. Change you parameter definition to match the table defn `char(2)` and it should then work.

Comment: yes, this worked. I also had to go through and change the rest of the parameters to match the table definitions